# Auto-indent new line when hitting enter to expand one-line tag in HTML

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to have this work flow working with HTML in Sublime Text 2:

1. Create HTML tag (e.g. ctrl + shift + W)
2. TAB (putting the cursor in the content area)
3. ENTER

Resulting with this (the word "HERE" indicates where the cursor should be):

```
<p>
    HERE
</p>
```

But instead this is what I get (the word "HERE" still indicating the cursor's position):

```
<p>
HERE</p>
```

Which demands you to

1. ENTER (again)
2. ARROW-UP + TAB
3. ARROW-UP + TAB (a second time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the following in your user key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\t$0\n"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "meta.scope.between-tag-pair", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My god, thank you so much! I had found a temporary solution where I after hitting ENTER did CMD + SHIFT + ENTER ("Insert line before"), but your solution is PERFECTION.
PS. Please remove the trailing comma though. Not possible for me to make an edit with less than 6 characters.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that. ST3 handles the commas better than ST2 :)