# Sublime Text 2 line break indentation

Tags: html, editor, sublimetext2, text-editor

```
<div>
This line needs to be indented and closing div tag should be in a new line</div>

<div>
  This result is what I want
</div>
```

In Sublime Text 2, after creating tags by pressing ctrl+shift+W and pressing "enter", I want the result be like above. Do I have to install plugin or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think you are trying to do the same as this issue - [Auto-indent new line when hitting enter to expand one-line tag in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750978/auto-indent-new-line-when-hitting-enter-to-expand-one-line-tag-in-html).

Below is my answer there.

---

Try adding the following in your user key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\n\t$0\n"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "meta.scope.between-tag-pair", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Awesome! Just one thing - the `,` (comma) before the closing brace `]` throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "reindent" , "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Reference: [Formatting HTML Code using Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888837/462627).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. This key binding is actually disabling ctrl+shift+w behaviour. The question is after I creating tags by pressing ctrl+shift+w and pressing enter, the new line should be indented. I am sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: No issues, anyways, you have got the answer I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a more general solution if you install the [Tag plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag). As stated [Dardub on his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858512/1392882), the Tag plugin is also available via [package control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

If you choose the Tag plugin, the easiest way to use it is highlight the text to indent and then press the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

If you insist on your <kbd>Enter</kbd> workflow just add this line to your key bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "tag_indent_document" }
```

But **beware** because it **replaces the** <kbd>Enter</kbd> **default behavior**.

A more conservative approach that avoids the need for text highlighting is to use a more specific binding:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+f"], "command": "tag_indent_document" }
```

And now to indent all the HTML/XML just press the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

#### References:

- [StackOverflow - Formatting HTML Code using Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839753/formatting-html-code-using-sublime-text-2)
- [GitHub - Tag Menu file](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag/blob/master/Main.sublime-menu)

Comment: Thank you Miguel, I will check it out.